# Lattix with Understand for C++/Objective-C: API library missing error (Mac OSX)

Tags: objective-c, ios, lattix

I'd like to use lattix to analyse objective-c code (http://www.lattix.com/node/114).
Computer is a macbook with osx 10.7.4.

Lattix version is 7.8 (newest).
I am not sure which understand version to use, newest would be 3.0 build 635, but I have the same problem with understand 3.0 and 2.6 anyway.

Understand works fine (version 2.6 or 3.0), I can create a new understand project for an iOS objective-c project and name it *.udb.
Analysis within understand also work fine.

The problem is when I try to import it into lattix:
In lattix I do:
File -> new project -> profiles: all -> choose Module Type C/C++ (Understand) and add the udb file.
When creating a new project now I get this error:
"Error opening data ... Understand API library missing. Please install Understand."

Also tried understand 3.0 same problem.
Has someone got these two tools working on a mac and maybe had a similar issue?

Or does s.o. maybe has an alternative to lattix?

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you have posted has the answer to your question at the third paragraph:

> Please ensure that Understand for C++ is installed on your computer
>   with a valid license. On Windows, please ensure that the path contains
>   the directory (typically C:\Program Files\STI\bin\pc-win32). **On
>   Linux, please set the environment variable STI_HOME to the top of your
>   Understand Installation**.

One [Japanese guide](http://www.techmatrix.co.jp/quality/lattix/faq_old.html) i found says

> [For Linux]
>
> After installing Understand 2.0, please set the
>   {Understand 2.0 installation directory} / scitools $ to STI_HOME
>   system environment variable.
>
> Start the ($ {Lattix installation
>   directory} / Lattix / bin / ldm.sh) Lattix.

Might be helpful for Understand 3.0 as well

Comment: Hi, thank you, I tried that acc. to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x     echo $STI_HOME saying /Applications/scitools which should be correct? (also tried Applications/scitools/bin/macosx) ... but it did not help ... tried hours now with different versions/entries always the same error :(

Comment: Please check the update, i'm not able to get the Lattix to test it yet.

Comment: waow, japanese guide, thank you very much for that hint ... unfortunately I cannot find a ldm.sh :( ... I only have the "lattix7.8.app" (size 75mb) file within the Mac Applications folder. (I hate this mac :X)

Comment: It might be the search algorithm, but hieroglyph forums used to give me the information i'm not able to find at english web, and google translation works surprisingly well for them. Back to the question, I'm out of suggestions but to contact the product support team as they definitely lacking clear documentation. Oh, i also noticed there's an installation guide at their site but it requires registration, I'm not very happy with it but you might want to give it a try.

Comment: yes thank you, I'd raise the useful score, but as a new user I'm not able to do so ...  I am out of suggestions too, maybe I'll try it under windows ... yes I already was in contact with the product support, but they seem to be out of suggestions too (I only have an eval licence fo tryout) ... but again big thanx.